# Does "output" always imply halting in computability?

Tags: terminology, computability, turing-machines

$L = \{P : P(n)$ outputs $n^2$ for all $n \in N  \}$

In questions of this nature, are we supposed to assume that "outputs" means "halts and outputs"? In modern programming languages, I can certainly "output" using a print statement and then have the program go into a loop after that.

Comment: What is $P$ here?

Comment: @Yoavbarsinai Presumably, $P$ is some program. Probably a Turing machine description but it doesn't make much difference if, for example, you wanted it to be a Java program.

Comment: I second David Richerby's answer. This is the only interpretation. Andrej Bauer is mentioning interesting related stuff, but your question asks about machines that halt and output the function $n^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of Turing machine is the content of the tape *when it halts*.

This is the standard definition. If a machine has written some string $s$ to its tape but hasn't halted yet, a straightforward reduction from the undecidability of the halting problem means that you have no way of knowing if it will ever write more characters to its tape, so you can't know if $s$ will be the "final" output. That means, for example, that you can't say that, if a non-halting computation never changes the string on the tape after the $t$th step, then the output is that unchanging tape string.

However, see [Andrej's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29405/9550) for a way of getting a well-defined output from a non-halting machine. The key point there is that the output tape is read-only so once a bit of the output has been written, you know that bit will never change.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Interestingly enough, it appears that L would be non R.E regardless. I posted a follow-up question that asks about that. Perhaps you could take a look? Thanks!

Comment: The machines @AndrejBauer mentions could also have (possibly) infinite outputs, i.e. the output is defined as the tape content in the limit.

Answer (score 4):

The *standard* way of treating Turing machines as things that accept intput and produce output is as follows:

- the input is written at the beginning of the tape in such a way we can tell where it ends,
- the rest of the tape is initially "empty", i.e., filled with a blank symbol,
- the output is whatever is on the tape when the machine halts
- if the machine does not halt, the output is *undefined*
- the machine is responsible for creating output from which we can actually tell where it ends (this is done easily with a bit of encoding, or there can be a special end-of-output symbol).

Such machines are sometimes called "type 1" (in order to distinguish them from "type 2" machines described below).

In computable analysis and several other areas we work with infinite representations (think about an infinite stream of digits of a real number). There we have the so called *type 2* machines:

- there is an read-only input tape which contains infinite input
- there are working tapes
- there is an output tape onto which the machine is allowed to write *exclusively* left-to-right once per cell, i.e., the only instruction for the output tape is "write symbol $x$ and move the head to the right"
- there is no halting state -- traditional halting may be indicated by outputing a special symbol on the output tape, but the machine keeps spinning

Type 2 machines never halt. Nevertheless, we can still compose them and observe what they are doing. Of course, in any finite amount of time only a finite amount of input is consumed and a finite amount of output is produced. A type 2 machine may diverge in the sense that it does not fill up the entire output tape.

Type 2 machines are convenient because they can operate on *non-computable* input, for instance, they can compute the square root *any* real number. In constrast, type 1 machines necessarily operate on computable reals, encoded by finite input which describes how to calculate approximations to the real.